# grep up to 3 spaces with \s

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

According to the following tutorials

1. https://linuxize.com/post/regular-expressions-in-grep/

> \s    Match a space.

and

2. https://www.guru99.com/linux-regular-expressions.html

> Some interval regular expressions are:
>
> Expression    Description
>
> {n}   Matches the preceding character appearing 'n' times exactly
>
> {n,m} Matches the preceding character appearing 'n' times but not more than m
>
> {n, } Matches the preceding character only when it appears 'n'
> times or more

Sample file

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat space.txt
0space
1 spaces
2  spaces
3   spaces
4    spaces
wolf@linux:~$
```

I just want to grep up to 3 spaces only, minimum 1 space, maximum 3 spaces
Unfortunately, it doesn't really work as expected.

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat space.txt | grep -P '\s{1,3}'
1 spaces
2  spaces
3   spaces
4    spaces
wolf@linux:~$ 

wolf@linux:~$ cat space.txt | grep -P '\s{3}'
3   spaces
4    spaces
wolf@linux:~$ 

wolf@linux:~$ cat space.txt | grep -P '\s{3,3}'
3   spaces
4    spaces
wolf@linux:~$ 

wolf@linux:~$ cat space.txt | grep -P '\s{0,3}'
0space
1 spaces
2  spaces
3   spaces
4    spaces
wolf@linux:~$
```

Desired Output

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat space.txt | grep -P '\s{0,3}' <- need to fix it here
1 spaces
2  spaces
3   spaces
wolf@linux:~$
```

Comment: Just a brief note regarding your problem. If you think of this with the letter 'a', you're trying to catch 'a', 'aa' & 'aaa'. But these patterns are all contained within the string 'aaaa', which is why it turns up in your results. You need to anchor the pattern in an appropriate way to get around that.

Comment: Thanks @Haxiel. I got it now. That's because PCRE grep is different from GNU grep.

Comment: @Wolf no, it has nothing to do with PCRE. It's the same in any regex flavor, which is why `echo aaaa | grep 'a'` works. Or, with extended (not PCRE) regular expressions and a specific number: `echo aaaa | grep -E 'a{1,2}'`. The braces mean "I need to find this many characters". Whether or not there are also more after or before the braces is irrelevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need:

```
grep -P '\S\s{1,3}\S' infile
```

`\s` matches a whitespace-character, *not only* a space.
`\S` matches a non-whitespace-character

in your attempt, you are not limiting that before &after your matches should not be a whitespace.

---

to filter on space only and avoid using PCRE, you can do:

```
grep '[^ ] \{1,3\}[^ ]' infile
```

or to work on lines having leading/trailing 1~3spaces:

```
grep '\([^ ]\|^\) \{1,3\}\([^ ]\|$\)' infile
```

[image: from https://regexper.com/]

input data (`cat -e infile`):

```
0space$
1 spaces$
2  spaces$
3   spaces$
4    spaces$
   3spaces$
    4space$
3spaces   $
4spaces    $
```

output:

```
1 spaces$
2  spaces$
3   spaces$
   3spaces$
3spaces   $
```

Comment: Your `\S\s{1,3}\S` will not match three spaces at the beginning or the end of the line.

Comment: @UncleBilly please continue reading the whole answer, I should not resolve everything to OP, there is hint that s/he can get help : )

Comment: I still don't get it: if you're using `-P` (pcre), why not `(?<!\s)\s{1,3}(?!\s)`?

Comment: Thanks @αғsнιη, I've got it. The problem was due to non-whitespace-character which is the numbers before the whitespace isn't it?

Comment: @Wolf no, the problem is "`you are not limiting that before &after your matches (minimum 1 and maximum 3 space here) should not be a whitespace`" and your grep matches line `4\ \ \ \ spaces` as well, since it matches condition "_line with at least 1 and at most 3 whitespaces_"

Answer (score 10):

If you want to match on a sequence of 1 to 3 whitespace characters not surrounded by whitespaces, that's where you'd use Perl look-around operators:

```
grep -P '(?<!\s)\s{1,3}(?!\s)'
```

It matches on:

```
         1
1234567890123456789
    a b  c   d    e
     ^ ^^ ^^^
```

With standard `grep`, you could achieve the same effect with:

```
grep -E '(^|[^[:space:]])[[:space:]]{1,3}([^[:space:]]|$)'
```

This time we match on the sequence of 1 to 3 whitespace characters and the non-whitespace on either side (or the start (`^`) or end (`$`) of the subject).

```
         1
1234567890123456789
   a b  c   d    e
^^^^ ^^^^
```

(with `-o` (a GNU extension), you'd find it doesn't report `a b` as `a` was already matched earlier; when searching for more matches, it starts at the next character after the last match).

Without `-E`, you get basic regexps that don't have alternation operators (though some `grep` implementations support `\|` for that as an extension), but standardly, you could still do:

```
grep -x '\(.*[^[:space:]]\)\{0,1\}[[:space:]]\{1,3\}\([^[:space:]].*\)\{0,1\}'
```

This time, the regexp matches the whole line including the 1 to 3 spaces and an optional (`\{0,1\}` the equivalent of ERE `?`) leading part to it ending in a non-whitespace and an optional part following it that starts with a non-whitespace.

```
         1
1234567890123456789
   a b  c   d    e
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In any case, those would still return lines that contain a sequence of 4 or more whitespaces as long as they also contain a sequence of 1 to 3 whitespace not surrounded by whitespaces.

If the point was to exclude lines containing sequences of 4 or more whitespaces then it would just be:

```
grep -vE '[[:space:]]{4}'
```

Or if you still require at least one whitespace, or in other words that the line contains one or more sequences of whitespace characters all of which have at least one whitespace but no more than 3:

```
grep -vE -e '[[:space:]]{4}' -e '^[^[:space:]]*$'
```

That is return all the lines except the ones that contain a sequence of 4 whitespace and the ones that are made exclusively of non-whitespaces.

Or again with Perl's look around operators:

```
grep -P '^(?=.*\s)(?!.*\s{4})'
```

That is match the beginning of the line, provided that it's followed by any amount of characters and a whitespace and that it's not followed by any amount of characters and a sequence of 4 whitespace.

Though it would be more legible with `sed` or `awk` where you can do both a positive and negative match in the same invocation:

```
awk '/[[:space:]]/ && ! /[[:space:]]{4}/'
```

```
sed '/[[:space:]]/!d; /[[:space:]]\{4\}/d'
```

Answer (score 6):

You can come up from the opposite. Exclude lines with more than 3 spaces in the substring.

```bsh
grep -Ev '\s{4,}'
```

`-v` Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
You can insert anchors as non-whitespace characters

```
grep -E '\S\s{1,3}\S'
```

Comment: Thanks @nezabudka, that's correct. However, I've just realized that my desired output was wrong. I've updated it. Any idea how to remove the 1st line using `-v` ?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, `\S` will need to match a character, which means that the second expression won't return lines where the spaces are located at the extreme start or end of the line.

Comment: @Kuslananda, Thanks. Of course, only for the specific case from the given example. Otherwise it should look like this: `grep -E '(^|\S)\s{1,3}(\S|$)'`

Answer (score -1):

```
$ grep -E '[[:space:]]' < file |
  grep -vE '[[:space:]]{4}'
1 spaces
2  spaces
3   spaces
```

- first filter all lines with atleast 1 space char.
- from these, filter out all lines with 4 or more space characters.
- what remains is lines comprising 1 to 3 space characters.

Comment: Like in @Kusalananda's now deleted answer, that does however not report lines that contain both sequences of 1 to 3 whitespace and sequences of more than 4 whitespace.

Comment: But is that not a contradiction? OTOH we want (1,3) spaces but don't want more than 4. Such cases needed to be worded unambiguously and not be left as a responsibility of the responders. At least the testcase shud show such at least.